# Replace variables in an HTML file and show it to the user

Tags: android, templates, android-webview

I have an HTML file which contains some variables like the current version of my app. These variables should be replaced before showing the HTML. Now my question is, what is the best approach for this?

- Where should I place the HTML file?
- How can I replace my variables?
- How can I show this HTML to the user?

Comment: I'd probably just use any generic templating system and load the template as a resource, do the replacement, and display normally.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to put the html file in assests.  Read the file in as text, do a string replace, and display it in a web view with WebView.loadData

Answer (score 0):

> Where should I place the HTML file?

You can store this file in assets folder,but I'm not clearly understand why you should change the values there.Try to provide more information.

> How can I replace my variables?

Why should you use html?Maybe it is better to use JSON or XML format?
You can take a look on java HTML parsers.

> How can I show this HTML to the user?

You simply can use WebView to load your html from file or to load it as a String.

Comment: I want to show the user how to use the app. For that I thought I prepare a html file with some variables. These should be replaced with the current values from my app. MAybe this makes it clearer what I want to achieve

Comment: Maybe you should put this variables in strings.xml so you can change them in more intelligent way.Also maybe you should just build some Activity instead of html file.